# Excel API data query - populates into a single column

Tags: macos, ms-office, settings, office-365

I am trying to populate some data from an API call. 
(Below is the process to get the same example)

Everything works fine until I hit the last button: all the data goes into the first column and does not seem to understand the separator.

[image: Coin market cap data into a single column]

Mind that my Language & Settings are for "United Kingdom" which should recognise comma as separator.

Process flow:

1. create text file with "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"
2. change the `.txt` file into `.iqy`
3. Open Excel, go to `Data` tab
4. `Get External Data` then `Run Saved Query`
5. Open the `.iqy` file
6. Select new sheet and you're good to go.

Thanks for the help,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are attempting to import data in [JSON format](http://www.json.org/example.html) which is not supported by Excel.

Doing a cursory search, I was able to find an [Excel plug-in that converts JSON to XLS](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104225427?src=office&tab=Overview) (Free).

I have not used this myself, so YMMV.